# block the button in html code on a certain conditions using JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, disable

I need the following - if LABEL value is Admin button "CHANGE" must be disabled without possibility to SUBMIT and if the label value is any other then SUBMIT is possible and button is enabled. I made the following code, but for some reason script work only for the second click, for the first click SUBMIT still works

```
<h3>ACCESS RIGHTS MANAGEMENT</h3>
<h5 style="color: gray"> User selected:</h5>
<h5 style="color: red">{{ context.user_name }}</h5>
<h5 style="color: gray"> Current role:</h5>
<h5 id="roll" style="color: red">{{ context.user_role }}</h5>

<h6 style="color: black">List of roles</h5>
<h7 style="color: grey">
{% for role in context.all_roles %}
<label>{{ role.get('name') }}</label>
{% endfor %}
</h7>
 <form method="post" action="/auth/editor/ {{ context.user_id }}" 
 class="row mt-3 text- center">
        <div class="col-auto">
                <div class="form-floating my-box">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" name="role"
placeholder="Input a new role" required>
            <label for="floatingInput">New Role:</label>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input id="button" onclick='disable()' display="false" type="submit" 
value="CHANGE" style="height: 58px" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"/>
            <script type = "text/javascript">

                function disable () {
                    let adm = document.getElementById("roll").textContent;
                    if (adm == "Admin") {
                    const button = document.querySelector('#button');
                    const disableButton = () => {
                    button.disabled = true;
                    };
                    button.addEventListener('click', disableButton);
                    document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = 'WARNING: You are cannot
 edit Admin';

                    } else {
                        const button = document.querySelector('#button');
                        const disableButton = () => {
                        button.disabled = false;
                    };
                }
                }
        </script>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label id="warning" style="color: red"></label>
        </div>
</form>
```

THanks!

Comment: just this should work `if (adm == "Admin") { event.preventdefault(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You are running your disable function only after the first click, you could try running it on page load to evaluate if it's going to be disabled on load.

For that run the function after declaring it:

```js
function disable() {
  let adm = document.getElementById("roll").textContent;
  if (adm == "Admin") {
    const button = document.querySelector('#button');
    const disableButton = () => {
      button.disabled = true;
    };
    button.addEventListener('click', disableButton);
    document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = 'WARNING: You are cannot edit Admin';

  } else {
    const button = document.querySelector('#button');
    const disableButton = () => {
      button.disabled = false;
    };
  }
}

// Add this
disable();
```